# Bootstrap 3: fixed column with responsive column

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to do responsive layout design for my website. How can I have the fixed width for the left column with responsive right column? Meaning, when size change on desktop level only the right column will change the width. Of course, when it turn into mobile screen view, the left column will become on top and right column will at the bottom.

I have tried by applying fixed width into the left column. But the problem is, when the screen size changed on desktop level, the right column move down to the bottom of left column.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="width=250px;" id="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent it from moving down and only moving down on mobile screen size? Thanks.

Comment: Bootstrap is based on [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) and they don't distinguish mobile device and desktop browser. So, if you will find solution - I don't think that it will be right one. Idea of responsive website is that user can use your website on mobile device, full screen browser or tiny browser window on desktop pc.

Comment: You should never use fixed pixels when using columns from Bootstrap. Let the user's device determine how wide the column should be instead, based on the full width of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
    </div>
</div>
```